# Kubernetes : Disadvantages of an all Master cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Hy !!
I was wondering if it could be possible to replicate an VMWare architecture in Kubernetes.
What I mean by that :
In place of having the Control-Panel always separated from the Worker Nodes, I would like to put them all together, at the end we would obtain a cluster of Master Nodes on which we can schedule applications. For now I'm using kata-container with containerd as such all applications are deployed in 'mini' VMs so there isn't the 'escape from the container' problem. The management of the Cluster would be done trough a special interface (eth0 1Gb). The users would be able to communicate with the apps that are deployed within the cluster trough another interface (eth1 10Gb). I would use Keepalived and HAProxy to elect my 'Main Master' and load balance the traffic.
The question might be 'why would you do that ?'. Well to assure High Availability at all time and reduce the management overhead, in place of having 2 sets of "entities" to manage (the control-plane and the worker nodes) simply reduce it to one, as such there won't be any problems such as  'I don't have more than 50% of my masters online so there won't be a leader elect', so now I would have to either eliminate master nodes from my cluster until the percentage of online master nodes > 50%, that would ask for technical intervention and as fast as possible which might result in human errors etc..
Another positive point would be the scaling, in place of having 2 parts of the cluster that I would need to scale (masters and workers) there would be only one, I would need to add another master/worker to the cluster and that's it. All the management traffic would be redirected to the Main Master that uses a Virtual IP (VIP) and in case of an overcharge the request would be redirected to another Node.
In the end I would have something resembling to this :
[Photo - Architecture VMWare-like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZFK3.png)

I try to find disadvantages to this kind of architecture, I know that there would be etcd traffic on each Node but how impactful is it ? I know that there will be wasted resources for the Pods of the control-plane on each node, but knowing that these pods (except etcd) wont do much beside waiting, how impactful would it be ? Having each Node being capable to take the Master role there won't be any down time. Right now if my control-plane (3 masters) go down I have to reboot them or find the solution as fast as possible before there's a problem with one of the apps that turn on the worker Nodes.
The topology I'm using right now resembles the following :
[Architecture basic Kubernetes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReR6W.png)
I'm new to kuberentes so the question might be seen as stupid but I would really like to know the advantages/disadvantages between the two and understand why it wouldn't be a good idea.

Thanks a lot for any help !! :slightly_smiling_face:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons for keeping control planes on their own. The big one is that you only want a small number of etcd nodes, usually 3 or 5 and that's usually the bounding factor on the size of the control plane. You usually want the ability to scale worker nodes independently from that. The second issue is Etcd is very sensitive to IOPS brownouts and can get bad cascade failures if the machine runs low on IOPS.

And given that you are doing things on top of VMWare anyway, the overhead of managing 3 vs 6 VMs is not generally a difference in kind. This seems like a false savings in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right the etcd would be the failing brick in all idea. I saw this kind of architecture was used by vSphere (the VMware Kubernetes solution) and in its documentation it shows a control plane on each ESiX, so I was wondering if it would be reproducible. I understood afterwards that they have the control planes on only 3 Nodes and they can be moved from node to node in case of failure but that's VMware magic, I don't see how to reproduce such behavior without a bunch of scripts and a lot of pain. Thanks for the help, I now understand why it won't work.